# Is there a verb that means "generated out of and by"?

Tags: word-request

What I mean by "generated out of" is that their material came out of X entity, and from is that they were created by X entity. I was thinking "born out of", but it's too general and doesn't mean "generated out of and generated by" I am pretty sure there's no verb for it, but there has to be a better sounding way to say it. "Generated out of and by" sounds like something from a philosophical book.

For example:

> These moon golems, made of moon rocks, ___ the moon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the real world, as opposed to soem fantasy world, this is a uniquely biological process, to have the same thing be both the source of materiel and the creator. For animals 9including humans) we use "born" perhaps in the constrution "born from" or "born of" to indicate the parent. This can also be used metaphorically: "Communism was born from socialism"

The verb "budded" as applied to a plant, or an amoeba or other 1-celled organism seems to fit your description msot closely, but ti doesn't seem to fit your example sentence well. In fant "made by" or "created by" seems to me about the only plausible fit to the example sentence

> These moon golems, made of moon rocks, ___ the moon.

This seems to imply that the moon is an aware creative entity, able to make things out of itself.. That is the realm of SF or fantasy, so no word for such a process has been coined and entered general use, that I know of.

(Note that a golem is traditionally made **from** a clay statue or image, but made **by** a person with piety {to invoke divine assistance} or power.)